# Connecting LPT2 to a remote printer - source already in use

Tags: windows, command-line, printer, network-printer

I am trying to connect to lpt2 a printer shared on the network but I always receive the following message:

> Source already in use

What could this be and how can I debug/fix this error? I am using the following command:

```
net use lpt2 "\\MyServer\RICOH MP C3000 PCL5c"
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure the share name (not printer name) is "RICOH MP C3000 PCL5c"? Also is something using LPT2? Check which ports your current printers are using. If all else fails install the driver on the system and use the IP address of the printer as the port.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `net use` to see what device names are already in use.

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           S:        \\servername\photos       Microsoft Windows Network
OK           LPT2      \\servername\laser1       Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

Use `net view \\computername` to see the share name of the printer.

```
Share name  Type   Used as  Comment

---------------------------------------------------
Laser1      Print           Laser1 (1200) PCL 6
photos      Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

In this case the share name is "Laser1" **not** "Laser1 (1200) PCL 6"

When mapping printers, normally you get an error message like this

```
C:\> net use lpt2 \\computername\printersharename
System error 85 has occurred.

The local device name is already in use.
```

What error number did you get?

Comment: As far as I know It is 85

Comment: Then `net use` will show you that `lpt2` is already in use, you can't assign it to two different printers at the same time. When you say "as far as I know" you seem uncertain - why?

Comment: It is 85. Sure and guaranteed. :)